# Issue in Delegate while passing data back to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a problem passing array data back from one view controller ("VC2") to another ("VC1"). I do everything by the rules. I made a proper `protocol` in VC1.

But unfortunately I could not get the data back.
This is my code:

**VC2**

```
protocol RecivedData {
    func dataRecived(nameArray: [String] , priceArray: [String])
}

var popUpdelegate : RecivedData?

@IBAction func nextBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Hello")
    let namedata = itemNameArr
    let namePrice = itemPriceArr

    self.popUpdelegate?.dataRecived(nameArray: namedata, priceArray: namePrice)
    print(namedata)
    print(namePrice)
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**VC1**

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController , RecivedData {
    func dataRecived(nameArray: [String], priceArray: [String]) {
        itemNameArr += nameArray
        itemPriceArr += priceArray
        print(itemNameArr, itemPriceArr)
        print ("This is HomeVC")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sendSegue"{
            let secondVC: AddOnItemPopUpVC = segue.destination as! AddOnItemPopUpVC
            secondVC.popUpdelegate = self
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: And your problem is? The delegate method never gets called or arrays are empty or...?

Comment: I Used print statement to check the data is going or not in VC2, And data is going from VC2 But Did not Received in VC1.

Comment: @hassanqureshi try to put in your prepare for segue function. Check this is printed or not

Comment: i used print statement in segue but didn't print that statement either  @chiragshah

Comment: @hassanqureshi means there is issue in your segue identifier check the identifier

Comment: Put a break point in the method [nextBtnTapped] and then check the 'popUpdelegate' object it should not be nil, and check the object type also it should be of type VC1, and your VC2 is AddOnItemPopUpVC !

Comment: i put a breakPoint on nextBtnTapped and the console showing data is pasing it shows all arrays data .. but the problem is in VC1 which is reciveng data .. chck my recving VC1 code .. And i also put a break point on VC1 dataRecived but it doesnot catch .. can u check that function ?

Comment: Why are you calling `removeFromSuperview`?  If you want to return to VC1 from VC2 then you should `dismiss` vc2. You can also possibly do this without the delegation by using an unwind segue. In `nxtButtonTapped` is `delegate` `nil`?  What triggers the segue from vc1 to vc2?  Can you show that code or is it just in the storyboard?

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with this

```
protocol RecivedData : class {
    func dataRecived(nameArray: [String] , priceArray: [String])
}
```

And

```
weak var popUpdelegate : RecivedData?
```

Now it will start working.

Make sure there will be no typo in segue name.

Comment: I used class keyword with my protocol and put break point on My Vc1 delegate Function print statement But he did not catch the print statement ..